# Python force tuple return type to required one use one line

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tuples

I have a function

```
function(input: str) -> Tuple[str, str]:

    return tuple(x for x in input.split(","))
```

The input is always 'value1, value2', however, I got an error message of: "Tuple[str, ...]", expected "Tuple[str, str]")

Is there anyway force the return type to the expected one just use one line of code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The interpreter has no idea how many elements `x for x in input.split(",")` will produce - from its perspective, `input` could be anything. Accordingly, it classifies the returned type as `Tuple[str, ...]`.

To get it to use a return type of `Tuple[str, str]`, which you marked the method as, you need to *explicitly* return exactly two elements:

```
def function(input: str) -> Tuple[str, str]:
    tup = input.split(',')
    return (tup[0], tup[1])
```

or otherwise, annotate the method differently.

---

as a one-liner you could use a list slice:

```
def function(input: str) -> Tuple[str, str]:
    return tuple(input.split(','))[:2]
```

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking not to duplicate the function of split

Second one is not working, still get the same error

Comment: You should probably slice the tuple, not the input to `tuple`.

Comment: Note: `input.partition()[::2]` would successfully guarantee exactly two elements and no data loss.

Comment: @chepner: Slicing first means less work spent creating a (potentially) large `tuple` only to slice it.

Comment: But necessary to make the type checker happy, no? (You could slice both, or use `input.split(",", 1)`; either one makes different assumptions about how to deal with strings with more than one `,`.)

Comment: partition() function works really well, thanks!